# Problem with AutoValidate when using format string on negative numbers

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I've got this format string "### ### ### ##0.00". It works well for positive number. But when I got negative number (for example -23.6), than I returns "-   23.60". That cause problem with AutoValidate on TextBox. I need to remove the three space between minus sign and number (spaces between numbers are no problem for validator). Which format string I have to use, to preserve format for positive numbers but which remove spaces between minus sign and number in negative numbers? For example if I got -1234567, then It gives me -1 234 567.00? I'm using .NET 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you consider using a comma instead of space in format string:

```
String.Format("###,###,###,##0.00", -23.60);
```

instead of

```
String.Format("### ### ### ##0.00", -23.60);
```

**EDIT to handle CZECH Culture Info**

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("cs-CZ");
String.Format("###,###,###,##0.00", -23.60, culture);   // outputs: -23,60
String.Format("###,###,###,##0.00", -123.60, culture);   // outputs: -123,60
String.Format("###,###,###,##0.00", -23.60, culture);   // outputs: -1 23,60
```

Comment: I want to preserve spaces. In this country comma means decimal separator.

Comment: Just curious as to which country is that? Also, you might want to pass the CultureInfo (for the Format method) if there is one for the country. Default uses "en-us".

Comment: Czech Republic. Decimal separator is solved, there is no problem.

Comment: So, don't you want the "-23.60" to be displayed as "-23,60". If yes, try the EDITed comment. Don't worry about the comma's in format string, you will still get it converted as spaces since the culture object knows spaces represent the GROUPING separator ---> http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/forms/v3r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.form.designer.locales.doc/i_xfdl_r_formats_cs_CZ.html

Comment: Problem is, that this app is deployed in some other countries to :) But I could try this mechanism there to. Thank you. By the way, I found on other forum this solution - "{0:N2}" which looks like working to. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: I thought you would want to group in thousands. Does N2 give you ability to group? I am not so sure, but you could be right. As to other countries, you might simply use a different string value for the CreateSpecificCulture method.

Comment: Yes, I tried N2 on some examples and looks like it's grouping well (even thousands).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Val(TextBox1.Text).ToString("#,#").Replace(",", " ")
```

Comment: I've got plenty of textbox fields and I cannot set it individualy. It's quite large app so I want to do it during parsing.